# Xampp over Lan - CSS/JS not working as they're redirecting to localhost

Tags: wordpress, xampp, lan

I'm trying to do work from a few computers at once, but the Wordpress installation on my main PC doesn't work from another two, they load it but with no JS or CSS when connecting via IP, check inspecting element on Chrome it's pointing them to localhost/.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You probably should change the wordpress base url in `wp_options` to the actual IP of the machine instead of using `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **wp-admin** > **settings** to check WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL) directly point to you IP address. You probably set localhost before.